# Decision tree completeness and unclassified data

Tags: classification, cart

I made a program that trains a decision tree built on the **ID3** algorithm using an **information gain** function (**Shanon entropy**) for feature selection (split).
Once I trained a decision tree I tested it to classify unseen data and I realized that some data instances cannot be classified: **there is no path on the tree that classifies the instance**.

An example (this is an illustration example but I encounter the same problem with a larger and more complex data set):

- Being **f1** and **f2** the predictor variables (features) and **y** the categorical variable, the values ranges are:

  - **f1**: [`a1`; `a2`; `a3`]
  - **f2**: [`b1`; `b2`; `b3`]
  - **y** : [`y1`; `y2`; `y3`]
- Training data:

  ```
  ("a1", "b1", "y1");
  ("a1", "b2", "y2");
  ("a2", "b3", "y3");
  ("a3", "b3", "y1");
  ```
- Trained tree:

  ```
       [f2] 
      / |  \ 
    b1  b2  b3 
    /    |   \ 
   y1   y2   [f1] 
             /  \ 
            a2   a3 
           /      \ 
          y3       y1
  ```

The instance `("a1", "b3")` cannot be classified with the given tree.
Several questions came up to me:

1. Does this situation have a name? *tree incompleteness* or something like that?
2. Is there a way to know if a decision tree will cover all combinations of unknown instances (all features values combinations)?
3. Does the reason of this *"incompleteness"* lie on the topology of the data set or on the algorithm used to train the decision tree (*ID3* in this case) (or other)?
4. Is there a method to classify these *unclassifiable* instances with the given decision tree? or one must use another tool (random forest, neural networks...)?

Comment: You can find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032127/decision-tree-completeness-and-unclassified-data) (cf. comments too).